# multiple () behind each other

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this in File %name%-audio.txt

```
00276.M2TS      4608 (0x1200)   0x90            PGS             eng (English)           5784.74                 36.554                  26,432,004      150,970
```

I need English as Variable and I use this script

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('%pathaddons%\sed -n "/4608/ { /PGS/ p; }" "%temp%\%name%-audio.txt"') do set PGS-A=%%f
for /f "delims=() tokens=7" %%a in ("%PGS-A%") do set PGS-A=%%a
if "%PGS-A%"=="" ( set PGS-A= ) ELSE (set SUB-1-FIN=%PGS-A% )
echo %SUB-1-FIN%
```

when I use this is output: 0x1200, how can set to second ()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count your tokens right: `1111111(2222)333333(4444)5555`

```
set "var=00276.M2TS      4608 (0x1200)   0x90            PGS             eng (English)           5784.74                 36.554                  26,432,004      150,970  "
for /f "tokens=4 delims=()" %%a in ("%var%") do echo %%a
```

Comment: You may want to stress that it's `tokens=4` not `tokens=7` as in the question.

Comment: nice wokring perfekt with 4